# Rollback LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, libstdc++

I tried to get this set up https://github.com/lob/lambda-pdftk-example

But I ran into a problem when I tried it on my ec2 instance. I cannot run mysqld after that. I get this error : `mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

Is there a way I can rollback?

Comment: Soft Link has been changed?

Comment: Did you create a snapshot or AMI before changing your system? If not, look into this for just these types of problems. I think that your problem is that MySQL is 64-bit and the library path now points to 32-bit libraries.

Comment: @BlooB guess so. How can I change it back?

Comment: @JohnHanley I didn't create a snapshot before this. Have been looking around but havent found anything

Comment: Do something like this: rm -f libstdc++.so.6     and      ln -s ./libstdc++.so.6.0.8 ./libstdc++.so.6  however do it according to the libraries you need

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that but did not get anywhere.